# No Application Permissions for Intune on Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune

As per (&today) https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#intune-device-management-permissions it says "Applications Permissions - None".

Is this going to remain that way or is it planned that at some point we will be able to access Intune as an application (running without a signed-in user present)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are considering adding this functionality, yes.  However, we don't have a committed timeline as of now.  But, we understand the customer and partner interest here, and thanks for helping keep this top of mind for us.

-Dave [MSFT]

Comment: Is there any update on this? The feature is much needed for InTune automation

Comment: No update at this time.  But, it continues to move forward in our development / spec process.